# How do I find out which textfield was not an integer

Tags: java, applet, try-catch, textfield

Basically I have created an applet that has three textfields one for each of the RGB values. I then created a try catch block to show a dialogue message if the user inputs a string. However, now I want it to find which textfield it was that had a string in it and set only that textfield to null so then they can type an integer, whilst also keeping the values of the two correct textfields.

So for example:

```
[255] [150] [cat]   
step 2: [255] [150] []  (the string textfield should become null)
```

Code:

```
try{
        if (e.getSource().equals (bttn))
        {

            as=T1.getText();
            ag=T2.getText();
            ab=T3.getText();
            as=as.trim();
            ag=ag.trim();
            ab=ab.trim();

            redColor= Integer.parseInt(as);
            greenColor= Integer.parseInt(ag);
            blueColor= Integer.parseInt(ab);
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException exception){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Integers Only","ERROR!",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split your code into tree parts, one for each field.

But this would result in redundant code. To avoid this, you should put the conversion part into a separate function which is called for each field.